# Перенести данные из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы, в обеих id_product - соответствует номеру товара.

**Table vy3j_product_lang**

id_product  |  description_short

**Table vy3j_product**

id_product  |  stock_id

Как из одной таблицы перенести один столбец в другой столбец другой таблицы?
Вариант:

```html
INSERT INTO vy3j_product (stock_id)
SELECT description_short FROM vy3j_product_lang
```

Просто добавляет в таблицу vy3j_product дополнительные строки с NULL значениями всех столбцов, кроме stock_id
а мне надо, чтобы stock_id добавлялся соответствующему id_product.
Перепробовала то, что знаю, но не получается заполнить столбец stock_id.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Сама себе отвечу:

```html
update vy3j_product, vy3j_product_lang
set stock_id=description_short
where vy3j_product_lang.id_product=vy3j_product.id_product;
select * from vy3j_product_lang;
```